# Throwing multiple exceptions of the same type at once

Tags: java, exception

My intent is to throw two `Exception`s at once. The code:

```
    String str = "foo";

    if (str.length() < 5) {
        throw new Exception("At least 5 characters."); // exception 1
    }

    if (!str.matches(".*[0-9]+.*")) {
        throw new Exception("At least 1 digit."); // exception 2
    }
```

`foo` is less than 5 characters long and doesn't contain any digits. But when I run this program, only `exception 1` is thrown.

How do I throw multiple exceptions (of the same type)? Or is my approach misled, and should I go about doing this differently?

Comment: maybe create your own exception `hasProblemAandBException`

Comment: This may be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) -- whatever your overall goal, this approach does not appear to be right. Consider presenting us information on a higher level, on the strategy level rather than telling us your low level tactics-level approach.

Comment: you could just store a list of errors that have occured (adding an error for each constraint that is not met), then throw an exception containing the list of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are checking against a list of possible problems, and you need to report *all* problems, then it may be neater to do it this way:

```
String str = "foo";

List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

if (str.length() < 5) {
    errors.add("At least 5 characters."); // exception 1
}

if (!str.matches(".*[0-9]+.*")) {
    errors.add("At least 1 digit."); // exception 2
}

// Check for more stuff

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception("There are problem(s) found:\n" + String.join("\n", errors));
}
```

Effectively, this is the same as what was proposed by other answers/comments, but this approach is a little cleaner/neater for a more complex scenario.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Instead test for the conditions you desire. Like,

```
String str = "foo";
boolean len = str.length() < 5;
boolean digit = !str.matches(".*[0-9]+.*");
if (len && digit) {
    throw new Exception("At least 5 characters and 1 digit."); // both 1 and 2
} else if (len) {
    throw new Exception("At least 5 characters."); // exception 1
} else if (digit) {
    throw new Exception("At least 1 digit."); // exception 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never throw more than one exception at a time, because they interrupt execution.  You could test for each possible problem individually, and throw an exception at the end which contains each failed test separated in a way that is easy to parse (commas would probably be best here).